# Latest version of MVC in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Just wanted to know the latest version of `MVC` for `.net framework`.

Googled and found no information regarding the `MVC history and the latest version`.

This site at `http://www.asp.net/mvc` has the tutorials for `MVC 5`. Does it mean that *MVC 5 is the latest* ?

I also find in google, some sites mentioning about `NuGet Gallery | Lib.Web.Mvc 6.0.1`. So, `6.1` is the latest ?

Or am I missing out some information/site which we can always refer to find out *whats the  latest in each framework and what more is coming ?*

Sorry if the question is too naive.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases

Comment: Latest release is 5.2.0 - http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can look here to see the latest releases http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/releases

So now MVC 5.2 is the latest.

Comment: Well explained with `where to`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

**ASP.NET MVC 4** is the latest version if you are using **.NET 4.**

**ASP.NET MVC 5** is the latest version if you are using **.NET 4.5.x.**

**MVC 6** in beta and will be shipped in future. The  `Lib.Web.Mvc 6.0.1` does not look part of ASP.NET MVC Packages.

Nuget Package can be shipped in any version so don't be confused.

There are 2 kinds of Nuget Package for ASP.NET MVC

 - Microsoft.Web.Mvc

 - System.Web.Mvc

System.Web.Mvc is used in ASP.NET MVC and Microsoft.Web.MVc is different things.

Answer (score 1):

Latest released version of MVC is 5. MVC 6 still in beta.

Comment: Sorry if answer partly duplicates comments to the question. Sometimes comments are not updated instantly.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of ASP.NET MVC is version 5 (5.2 to be precise).

It's also worth mentioning that `Lib.Web.Mvc` is not the MVC framework, but a set of extensions for the ASP.NET MVC framework. This can be found [here](https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc)